# cannot open source file in VSCode on Linux (ms-vscode.cpptools)

Tags: c, linux, file, visual-studio-code

So I ran into this error today when working with GTK-3.0, Linux seems to be confused about how to include header files, because normally I'd use `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` but because that doesn't work I have to add `<gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>`. This is what my `c_cpp_properties.json` file looks like.

---

Adding `/usr/include/gtk-3.0` seemed like a solution, but because `gtk.h` is dependent on other libraries I have to find out how I can make VSCode look for files recursively. I already tried `/usr/local/include/*` but with no success.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "defines": [],
            "includePath": [
                "/usr/local/include",           
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `pkg-config` command is usually used to determine all the dependancies and flags needed.

The output of `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` should give you all the compiler flags and `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` all the linker flags.

`pkg-config` also has a `--static` flag if you need static linking (which requires more dependancies to be linked) and a `--msvc-syntax` flag to generate MSVC-style flags.

Usually you call these commands in your configure or build tools (e.g. in `Makefile` or in `configure`). Even if you use Code::Blocks you can call `pkg-config` by surrounding it with backticks.

Comment: Am I supposed to add all those paths to c_cpp_properties.json? Isn't there a permanent fix?

Comment: I don't know what you use that .json file for, but usually you call these commands in your configure or build tools (e.g. in `Makefile` or in `./configure`). Even if you use Code::Blocks you can call `pkg-config` by surrounding it with backticks. In fact, I don't see why you're not building with `./configure` and `make` since you're on Linux...

Comment: Yes, I am compiling by hand, but currently I'm reading the documentation on Makefile to use that instead.

Comment: @sachiel2008 If I may give you a tip: `Makefile` is old and very general. It knows nothing about building for Windows. Autoconf tools are slightly better at that. But if you are learning something new you should point your attention to more modern build systems like CMake, which works well on many platforms including Windows. And if you combine CMake with Ninja instead of Make it builds really fast.